# See if any term is in a block of text

Tags: python

I have some text and I'm looking to see if any 'software-related' terms are in it. Here's a basic implementation:

```
def is_software_related(text):
    TERMS = ['software', 'developer', 'java', 'ruby', 'python']
    for term in TERMS:
        if term in text.lower(): return True
    return False
```

Is there a more elegant one-liner to do the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Generator:**

There are a few other generator solutions but this may be the easiest to read:

```
def is_software_related(text):
    return any(term in text.lower() for term in ['software', 'developer', 'java', 'ruby', 'python'])
```

**Set Intersection:**

If you only want to match full words, you can do it with a set intersection (create a set of software-related words and another set of words in the text, and see if they share any members):

```
def is_software_related(text):
    return bool({'software', 'developer', 'java', 'ruby', 'python'} & set(text.lower().split()))
```

This is arguably less readable than just using a for loop, though, and definitely less readable than the generator. Note that it yields different behavior than solutions which use `in` (since `in` will allow partial matches, like `javanese`, while set intersection won't). This may be preferable behavior for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote can be written with the following one-liner:

```
def is_software_related(text):
    return any(map(text.lower().__contains__, ('software', 'developer', 'java', 'ruby', 'python')))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line, with `any`.

```
any(map(lambda x: x in text.lower(), TERMS))
```

Comment: I think that's pretty simple to read -- I like that solution.

Comment: Yeah, this is fairly idiomatic. i wrote the "not pretty" header, then realized it was actually fairly straightforward and forgot to remove the header.